# Manipulating form's control in BusinessLogic layer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, architecture, layered

I am new to .net programming. 
I am developing a windows application(C#), in which i am using Layered Architecture (3 layers [**View layer**, **Business-logic layer** and **Data-access layer**]). But am stuck between concept of View layer and BusinessLogic layer. E.g.
Let in my Form there are many DataGridVew control in same winform, and i have to do some manipulation on them that's why i created a common method for similar manipulation say GetRecordCount(..)

```
private int GetRecordCount(DatagridView dgv)
{
     //calculate record row count and return that.
}
```

My question is :: Where should i put `GetRecordCount(..)` method , in ViewLayer or BusinessLogic layer ?
If we put `GetRecordCount(..)` in BusinessLogic layer then is it good to pass win controls in BusinessLogic layer as argument for manipulation b'coz winform controls are the part of ViewLayer?

Comment: why do you have to write a method since datagridview already provided `Datagridview.Rows.Count` property to get row count?

Comment: Doan Cuong :that is just an example of manipulation.

Comment: In these cases, I used to use a static class that will be used across my `ViewLayer` to manipulate `View control`. I don't think put it in `BusinessLogic` is a good idea because it will be hard to reuse your `BusinessLogic` in another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The business layer should only make decisions/calculations to support your business model. In my opinion the `GetRecordCount` **should not be in the business layer**. You should not by any way pass elements of the UI to the business model to manipulate them. The view/UI layer should handle all the displaying details, using the calculations/decisions of the business layer.

This specific calculation is **a calculation only for display purposes** and will not be used for any other purpose as it calculates the rows of a **datagridview**. If another method would return the total number of records included in the system, I would probably put it on the business layer. But in this case, the method should go to the UI layer.

Hope I helped!